# Not able to find artifact jackson-modules-java8 jar

Tags: java, maven

I am using pom.xml like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but there is no .jar available in public repo. It have only .pom file in respective release. [Public maven repository link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-modules-java8/)

How to get .jar for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually download `.zip` for respective release from [jackson-modules-java8/releases](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/releases) 
and build it locally using command.

```
mvn clean install
```

It will give you .jar for each module under respective target directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also include that dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-modules-java8</artifactId>
    <version><!-- same version as your other jackson dependencies --></version>
</dependency>
```