# Could not find artifact Jackson-modules-java8:jar

Tags: maven, jackson, java-10

I use **open-jdk-10**.

```
mvn clean install
```

Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8:jar:2.9.8 in" central"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-modules-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

without `jackson-modules-java8` it builds successfully.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-modules-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472779/not-able-to-find-artifact-jackson-modules-java8-jar) question, but it does not solve my problem. I have maven dependency in my pom file. Downloading things manually is the last thing I will do if nothing else works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On GitHub [`jackson-datatype-jsr310`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) page you can read:

> (DEPRECATED) -- moved under `jackson-modules-java8` repo:
>   https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

On [linked](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8#usage) page you can find info about `java8` module:

> Note that the parent project -- jackson-modules-java8 -- is ONLY used
>   as parent pom by individual "child" modules, and DOES NOT have
>   dependencies on them.

and how new modules should be used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Links to Maven Repositories:

1. [jackson-datatype-jdk8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.8)
2. [All com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype modules](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype)

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between `jackson-datatype-jsr310` and `jackson-datatype-jdk8`? Do I really need both?

Comment: @YanKhonski, `Java 8 Datatypes`: support for other new Java 8 datatypes outside of date/time: most notably `Optional`, `OptionalLong`, `OptionalDouble`. `Java 8 Date/time`: support for `Java 8` `date`/`time` types (specified in `JSR-310` specification) . So, making it shorter: `JDK8` contains many classes from `Java 8` except `time` related and `jsr310` conatins only `time` related classes from `Java 8`. For more info, read [Overview](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8#overview)

Answer (score 1):

I removed java8-module.

I use instead

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I do not know what the difference is between `jackson-modules-java8` and `jackson-datatype-jsr310`, but the latter works for me.

When you create an object mapper, register `JavaTimeModule`.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```